# What the weather condition can affect for flight?

Tags: weather

What is the most disturbing weather conditions for flight? 
On another word: what more dangerous for takeoff/landing: wind, precipitation or something else?

Comment: Hi and welcome. What kind of plane are we talking about? A light plane? A 747? A helicopter? And based on what? Past accident rates? Flight cancellations? Special training required? Please edit the question to add the relevant information.

Comment: I am working with a prediction model for delay regular flights and wondering what can be more important for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually fairly simple when talking about weather related dispatch delays for the airlines.

Number one items:

In summer, thunderstorms, especially those associated with fronts and squall lines.

In winter, snowstorms with heavy accumulations, or severe freezing rain.

And beyond that, in both summer and winter, extreme low visibility, as in fog.